Azure Devops odata query returns UserEmail:Unknown
I'm trying to get a list of WorkItems together with the assignees. However no matter what I try, I get this output:
{
"@odata.context":"https://tfs.akbank.com/DefaultCollection/AkbankIT/_odata/v3.0-preview/$metadata#WorkItems(WorkItemId,AssignedTo(UserName,UserId,UserEmail,UserType),Teams(TeamName))",
"value":[
{"WorkItemId":3010036,
"AssignedTo":{
    "UserId":"aa490a50-14cb-4282-92ab-f4facddcfcfc",
    "UserName":"John Doe (John's Department)",
    "UserEmail":"Unknown",
    "UserType":null
    },
"Teams":[{"TeamName":"MyTeam"}]}]}

When I open the WorkItem in the UI, I can see the person it's assigned to. What can be the problem?
I check the API documentation and SO for AD Odata questions with no luck.
Here is the odata url I'm trying: https://tfs.akbank.com/DefaultCollection/AkbankIT/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$select=WorkItemId&$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName, UserId, UserEmail, UserType), Teams($select=TeamName)&$filter=WorkItemId eq 3010036

With your Odata structure, I can reproduce the same on my On-prem DevOps server:

The issue should be caused by the account itself, since the user comes from local machine/domain, it could not have email configured, which results it cannot get the email info.
You can get the account details by its id to confirm if it contains the email.

I also tried same Odata in Cloud service(change to https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}), confirmed the email display well.

Edit:
As we confirmed, your identity has email value, but cannot return from odata url. It's recommended to report it in Developer Community. Thanks.

When I use WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemAsync, I can see that assignee's unique name is returned. Does not this show that the account (of the assignee, right?) is not local? Why is unique name not returned from odata?

As per the doc, the userEMail is the Email associated with a user account identity. It could be different with the assignee. Can you use the rest api account details by its id to confirm the email value?

Please remove project nam Ak**IT in the url.

You're right Wade, now I got "Mail": {
"$type": "System.String",
"$value": "john.doe@akbank.com"
} but I cannot get this value from odata?

Where do you put the odata url? As per the doc, certain client tools can abuse direct entity addressing. Can you give a try to put the odata url in web browser, does it return usermail correctly?

No it's the same when I open the odata url in browser.

Thanks for confirmation. Since the odata query can return useremail attribute correctly from Cloud service, but cannot return on local ADO server, it's recommended to report it in the Developer community, you can also share the link so we can track for you, thanks.

Thanks for the update Wade. What about the Account property, can I get it from odata? Here is the account detail I get when I query by id: "Account":{"$type":"System.String","$value":"N12345"}

The Account property is returned from identity rest api, not the odata url. but it's same with the UserName returned in odata url.

In our setup UserName returned from odata is name surname, whereas rest api returns corporate id in Account. We actually need corporate id or email.

I checked with all entity of work item in Odata, but not found other entity about the user corporate id or email. It's recommended to raise the ticket in Developer community for the UserEmail entity on local server.
